# Drop down menu changes email in form

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="mailto:mariamcsorley@hotmail.com">


<p> Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME= "name" SIZE="30"> </p>
<p> Email: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME= "email" SIZE="30"> </p>
<p> Phone: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME= "telephone" SIZE="30"> </p>

<p> Practice: <SELECT NAME= "practice" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Select Practice*
<OPTION>Dungannon
<OPTION>Cookstown
<OPTION>Coalisland
<OPTION>Portnaglone
<OPTION>Aughnacloy
</SELECT> </p>

<p> Species: <SELECT NAME= "species" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Select Species*
<OPTION>Small Animal
<OPTION>Equine
<OPTION>Farm
<OPTION>Pig
<OPTION>Poultry
</SELECT> </p>

<p> Preferred Date: <SELECT NAME= "day" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Day* <OPTION>01 <OPTION>02 <OPTION>03 <OPTION>04 <OPTION>05 <OPTION>06 <OPTION>07 <OPTION>08 <OPTION>09 <OPTION>10 <OPTION>11 <OPTION>12 <OPTION>13 <OPTION>14 <OPTION>15 <OPTION>16 <OPTION>17 <OPTION>18 <OPTION>19 <OPTION>20 <OPTION>21 <OPTION>22 <OPTION>23 <OPTION>24 <OPTION>25 <OPTION>26 <OPTION>27 <OPTION>28 <OPTION>29 <OPTION>30 <OPTION>31 </SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="month" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Month* <OPTION>Jan <OPTION>Feb <OPTION>Mar <OPTION>Apr <OPTION>May <OPTION>Jun <OPTION>Jul <OPTION>Aug <OPTION>Sep <OPTION>Oct <OPTION>Nov <OPTION>Dec </SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="year" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Year* <OPTION>2016 <OPTION>2017 <OPTION>2018 <OPTION>2019 <OPTION>2020 <OPTION>2021 <OPTION>2022 <OPTION>2023 <OPTION>2024 <OPTION>2025 <OPTION>2026 <OPTION>2027 </SELECT> </p>


<p> Preferred Time: <SELECT NAME="hour" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Hour* <OPTION>08 <OPTION>09 <OPTION>10 <OPTION>11 <OPTION>12 <OPTION>13 <OPTION>14 <OPTION>15 <OPTION>16 <OPTION>17 <OPTION>18 <OPTION>19 <OPTION>20 </SELECT>

<SELECT NAME="minute" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>*Minute* <OPTION>00 <OPTION>15 <OPTION>30 <OPTION>45 </SELECT> </p>


<p> Details: <TEXTAREA NAME="details" ROWS=6 COLS=40>
</TEXTAREA> </p>

<INPUT TYPE="submit">
</form>
```

Hi there, Is there any way at all that I can use php or a function in order to change the email as the practice is changed. For example when Dungannon is selected from the practice drop down menu that dungannon@dungannon.com is emailed and when Coalisland is selected it emails the form to coalisland@coalisland.com?

I know nothing about this and so have been trying to figure it out and googling solutions but I cant seem to get anything to work - any help is appreciated greatly... thank you!

Comment: Is your backend [tag:java] based or [tag:php] based, you tagged your question with both tags

Comment: are you using juqery?

Comment: what result you want ? and please describe it more

Comment: show us a code for `newhotpartgenerate.php`

Comment: The options in the select menus do not have a value assigned and you neglected to share the javascript code, especially the function `checkform` so it is difficult to answer - but yes, with some crafty javascript you can do it

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's java based? as I say i am pretty new to this. If there's an easier/better way to do it I can change it.

Comment: I basically want a form and depending on the practice selected it emails that practice the form information. I'm adding it into an app i am creating on AppyPie.com?

Comment: I think people may have picked me up wrong and I probably explained it rather strangely. When the practice information is changed I could like it to then email that particular practice so when dungannon is selected from the practice drop down menu it is sent to dungannon@dungannon.co.uk
I have no idea how to do this, complete newbie

Answer (score 1):

Change your html code

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="email" NAME= "email" SIZE="30"> <br>
```

and

```
 Practice: <SELECT NAME= "practice" SIZE="1"onChange="getData(this);">
      <OPTION SELECTED>*Select Practice*
      <OPTION>Dungannon
      <OPTION>Cookstown
      <OPTION>Coalisland
      <OPTION>Portnaglone
      <OPTION>Aughnacloy
</SELECT>
```

Javascirpt code

```
function getData(title)
{
     var selectedText = title.options[title.selectedIndex].text
     var emailValue="";
     if(selectedText=="Dungannon")
     {
         emailValue = "dungannon@dungannon.co.uk";
     }
     else if(selectedText=="Cookstown"){
         emailValue= "cookstown@cookstown.co.uk";
     }
     document.getElementById("email").value = emailValue;
 }
```

Here is working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWXbPr)

Answer (score 0):

To set the email address in your form element, modify the html to include the `onchange` event handler as below and then add the javascript below.

```
<p> practice: <select name="practice" onchange='setemail(this.value)'>
    <option selected hidden='true'>*select practice*
    <option value='dungannon'>dungannon
    <option value='cookstown'>cookstown
    <option value='coalisland'>coalisland
    <option value='portnaglone'>portnaglone
    <option value='aughnacloy'>aughnacloy
</select> </p>

<script>
    function setemail(value){
        /* to change form action */
        document.querySelectorAll('form[name="frmhot"]')[0].setAttribute('action','mailto:'+value+'@'+value+'.co.uk' );
        /* to set value of text field called `email` */
        document.querySelectorAll('form[name="frmhot"] input[type="text"][name="email"]')[0].value=value+'@'+value+'.com';
    }
</script>
```

I notice that the form method has been changed to your email address - I'm not 100% sure that this will work as you expect but if you wish to change the form action instead of / or as well as changing the value of the email field in the form then a slight modification to the javascript function is required.

Setting the form action as a `mailto` will most likely invoke the mail client on the client computer ( not sure how it would work on a mobile ) - is that the intended method of operation or is it supposed to send the email directly?

---

### From @OP:

It's for an app so I have one page of code to do this on so would have to put the  tag in if I was to do a function. I am clueless but when you click submit I want it to be able to change to email the practice.. am i explaining this correctly?

Comment: the above code will change the form action and will set the value of the email text field. What it will not do, when the form is submitted, is actually send an email to which ever address is selected or the default form action which is your email address. To actually sent the email you will need som serverside code or perhaps a java applet might be used ( I don't know Java so can't help with that )